# Check for previously consumed purchases

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I want to disable ads in an app whenever a user purchases a consumable virtual currency item. Is there any was to check if a consumable purchase has been bought before - from the documentation it looks like the status of the purchase is set to unowned once consumed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, you are correct - getPurchases() will only return the un-consumed purchases.

A way around this would be storing a boolean in your SharedPreferences for each item purchased.  When you read the value, set the default to false.

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean isPurchased = myPrefs.getBoolean(PURCHASED_ITEM_001, false);
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the only way. Was hoping to avoid this as the SharedPreference will be lost with an uninstall.

Comment: I know it's been quite some time, but I was looking for an alternative because setting a preference does not account for refunds. Unfortunately, we now have a society of people that purchase items and perform chargebacks to keep the item without paying.

Comment: This is not correct, since user can reinstall the app and you will lost this SharedPreferences and his/her previous purchase will come up as active. Check out; https://stackoverflow.com/a/55211744/1847645

Answer (score 1):

use [`queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient#queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(java.lang.String,%20com.android.billingclient.api.PurchaseHistoryResponseListener))

> Returns the most recent purchase made by the user for each SKU, **even if that purchase is expired, canceled, or consumed.**

And check if any of the [`Purchase.sku`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/Purchase.html#getSku())'s in the response match the SKU...of the item you care about.